# android set custom backgorund color to wintow title of Theme.Holo.Light themed applicatin

Tags: android, light, android-theme

I am trying to set custom background colour to title of Theme.Holo.Light application with below xml. But it doesn't work.

Theme.Holo.Light somehow overrides @style/WindowTitleBackground

if I set parent to just android:Theme, it works fine. I want to ave Halo.Light theme but with different background. I have seen custom background layout samples but as I am learning I don't want to go in to that.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

```
<style name="theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item> 
</style>
<style name="WindowTitleBackground">     
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>                   
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use `android:background`, it must be drawable resource, so using value such as **#ff234562** directly will not be valid,in fact you should define the value in **colors.xml** first,then use like this

```
<item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Android uses bitmaps for that value (either @null or @android:drawable/title_bar).

Try creating a black png and use it instead of the color code:

```
<style name="WindowTitleBackground">     
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/black</item>                   
</style>
```

Comment: <style name="WindowTitleBackground">     
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/title_bg</item>                   
    </style>   didn't work